# get tickpositions highcharts

Tags: highcharts, freemarker, scatter-plot

I have a highcharts scatter plot for which I'm trying to fetch the x and y tickPositions in freemarker template, specifically the first and last one. Such as that I would get something as [-10,-10] (bottom left corner) at the intersection of the x-y axis and [30,40] (top right corner) at the intersection of the opposite sides, where xAxis ticks are [-10,0,10,20,30] and yAxis ticks are [-10,0,10,20,30,40]

I want these points so that I'll be able to plot a diagonal line across the scatter plot from bottom lower corner to top right corner. The line series should look like:

```
series: [
        {
            type : 'line',
            <#--diagonal line-->
            data :[[-10,-10], [30,40]], // to be calculated dynamically
            lineWidth: 0.5,
            marker : {
                enabled : false
            }
        },
        {
            color: 'rgb(0,85,152)',
            data: [[2,3],[6,7],[8,9]]
        }
]
```

The problem at present is I'm unable to get [-10,-10], [30,40] data points. Is it even possible is what I'm wondering. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the question has a suitable answer. I would be careful using the term regression line to refer to this. Linear regression is much more robust than simply drawing a line based on the axis scaling...  If you're counting on that line to tell you what a regression line would, you'll need to do more than that.

Comment: @jlbriggs I see. Well I simply want to draw a line, not looking for linear regression. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @jlbriggs I edited the question accordingly

Comment: @shweta Why are you unable to get `[-10,-10],[30,40]` data points? Do you want to just draw diagonal line for plot area? You could use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) for that. You want to have line calculated dynamically - based on line being diagonal or is there something more?

Comment: @KacperMadej I just want diagonal line for plot area calculated dynamically. My problem jsfiddle links are in comments below.

Comment: @shweta Lolylulu answer should resolve your problem, but I added another solution in another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `getExtremes()` function on an axis.
For example:

```
var extremes = $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].getExtremes();
```

Here is the [doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes), and here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwjdpb69/3/)

Is this what you were trying to achieve ?

**Edit**

After your fiddle example, I understand better your need.
Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/h5gb6da5/2/)

```
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  var extremeY = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
  var extremeX = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();

  var lineSeries = {
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        [extremeX.min, extremeY.min],
        [extremeX.max, extremeY.max]
      ],
      lineWidth: 0.5,
      lineColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };

  chart.addSeries(lineSeries);
```

I created an object with the properties of the line series. And using `min` and `max` (not `dataMin` and `dataMax`) properties from the object returned by `getExtremes()` you obtain the desired result.

**Edit 2**

You could put this code in the `load` event of the chart. It is a callback called after the chart finished loading. And here you can use `this` to refer to the chart :

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var extremeY = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
          var extremeX = this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();

          var lineSeries = {
            type: 'line',
            data: [
              [extremeX.min, extremeY.min],
              [extremeX.max, extremeY.max]
            ],
            lineWidth: 0.5,
            lineColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
          };

          this.addSeries(lineSeries);
        }
      },
      //...
});
```

Here is the [new updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/h5gb6da5/6/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! It got me moving in some direction. But I want to use min/max axis values not data values to plot the line. Can you see this: [scatter diagonal line fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shwetakarol/uwjdpb69/5/)
How to do this in freemarker template?

Comment: @shweta By freemarker template you mean that you want to set the line server side in Java? If line should be calculated dynamically based on chart, then you could set up JS code in chart - that way you would have to predict what will Highcharts do, but let some JS code run on client side and adjust dynamically.

Comment: @KacperMadej Can you please have a look at this fiddle: [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shwetakarol/h5gb6da5/1/)
Here you see that data :[[-100,-100], [100, 100]] is chosen arbitrarily to be able to draw the line. However I want this to be dynamically calculated to reflect just the plot area corners [-10,-10][30,30]

Comment: @KacperMadej Because the problem with approach in above [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shwetakarol/h5gb6da5/1/) is shown here: [problem demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shwetakarol/96877jhy/1/) 
Arbitrary line points do not work for a data set having only positive values and the diagonal line doesn't plot corner to corner!

Comment: @shweta here you go, I updated the answer, hope this is what you needed

Comment: Lulylulu this indeed works in the jsfiddle, thanks for the update. And now I want to fit this into my FTL template because the ftl doesn't recognize $('#chart-divId').highcharts() syntax so I have to find out a way to get the chart reference in ftl.

Comment: @shweta I don't really know how FTL works so I updated my answer with a possible solution. Let me know if this can work for you.

Comment: Lulylulu no words enough to thank you. This is exactly what I needed :-) 
Trick is to use the "load" event....great learning it was.
One correction in the fiddle though, for the line series data change [extremeX.max, extremeX.max] to [extremeX.max, extremeY.max]

Comment: Glad I could help. I also fixed the typos.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only a diagonal path, then you could add it using [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cr7gq4st/

```
function diagonal() {
    var chart = this,
            ren = chart.renderer,
        diag = chart.diag,
        attrs = {
            'stroke-width': 0.5,
          stroke: '#000',
          zIndex: 1
        },
        topR = {
            x: chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth,
          y: chart.plotTop
        },
        bottomL = {
            x: chart.plotLeft,
          y: chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight
        },
        d = 'M ' + bottomL.x + ' ' + bottomL.y + ' L ' + topR.x + ' ' + topR.y;
    if( !diag ) { //if doesn't exist, then create
        chart.diag = ren.path().attr(attrs).add();
    }
    chart.diag.attr({d:d});
}
```

Comment: thanks so much I shall try these solutions tomorrow and come back with my update